# Why does mpdf embed whole glyphs when the pdfa option is enabled?

Tags: mpdf

Today I have found that PDF/A files generated by mpdf are very huge (I am using some CJK fonts), possibly due to inclusion of the complete glyphs.  However, those created by commercial pdf applications (e.g. Adobe Acrobat, FoxIt, etc.) do embed subsets of the glyphs (for characters actually used in a document), even though the PDF/A option is enabled. Why does mpdf embed whole glyphs when the `PDFA` parameter is enabled?

Comment: Are you sure this is a question for this website? Isn't it more appropriate to ask it on the [Graphic Design StackExchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)? Or [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)?

Comment: mpdf developers recommend stackoverflow.  edit: add github link (https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf.github.io/issues/new)

Comment: How are you initialising mPDF in PHP? Can you post a small snippet of the HTML you are writing to the PDF which replicates this problem?